# Use different Stylesheets in different components Angular Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, bootstrap-4, angular-components

I am working on one Angular Webpack project in which I have to develop new design for the webpages.

The previous developer built all webpages using Typebase.css by referencing it in index.html file.

Now I want to use bootstrap for my all designs. And when I am trying to use it then  my all CSS is mess up between Typebase and bootstrap.

Is there any way that I can use only bootstrap for my new design components and Only Typebase in older webpage’s components until final product built up?

I have tried styleUrls option but no success. So can I include the stylesheet in in styleUrls not globally? If yes then how.

Thank you in advance for any small help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay if there is a container component for all the old web pages so you can do the following in that component:

```
constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

ngOnInit() {
  let styleSheet = this.document.getElementById('your_style_link_id');
  //REMOVE IT 
}
```

So first of all you should include both styles on index.html and give each of them an ID.

After that, at the container component for the old pages, you should remove "bootstrap" and add your old style sheet and at the container component of the new pages you should remove the old style sheet and add bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks Nour. Your logic works. Here is my code                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     let styleSheet1  = document.styleSheets[1];
styleSheet1.disabled = true;

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do.

1. First you need to remove Typebase.css from your index.html
2. Add Typebase.css in each old component explicitly
   eg: @Component({
   selector: 'selectorName',
   templateUrl: 'templateUrl'
   styleUrls: ['./Typebase.css']
   })
3. Same way you can add your bootstrap.css file in styleUrls to your new components.

Not cleanest way but this should work.